# Show a default Image for primeNg file upload

Tags: angular, primeng

I want to provide a default image to drag-drop area of the PrimeNG file upload component.

I tried to specify the image using img src="logo.png". But it does not work.

**Code**

```
 <p-fileUpload [showUploadButton]="false" (onSelect)="onSelectImage($event.files)" (uploadHandler)="myUploader($event)" accept="image/*" customUpload="true"
                  maxFileSize="200000" name="myfile[]" styleClass="file" url="./upload.php" (onClear)="onClear($event)">
      <ng-template pTemplate="toolbar">
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template let-file pTemplate="file" class="dragdrop-area">
       <img [src]="imgURL" height="320px" width="200px" *ngIf="isFileCompatible">
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template pTemplate="content">
        <div class="dragdrop-area" *ngIf="!isImageUploaded">
          <img src="logo.png"/>
          <p style="text-align: center;padding-top: 40%">Drag and Drop Here</p></div>
      </ng-template>
    </p-fileUpload>
```

Can anyone please tell me how can do it?[image]

Comment: Are you sure that logo.png is in the same directory? You can open the console and check the error that tells the url

Comment: yes checked. the url is correct

Comment: can you show a snapshot of your folder structure

Comment: your image path should be correct